# Printing out an array to a file

Tags: php, html

I'm stuck on particular task. As you can see I'm extracting hrefs and title from webpage and I need to put this information to a file. But how this array can be printed in order like this: href1 : title1 , href2 : title2 and so on.

```
   <?php
   $searched = file_get_contents('http://technologijos.lt');
   $xml = new DOMDocument();
   @$xml->loadHTML($searched);
   foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $lnk) 
      {
         $links[] = array(
         'href' => $lnk->getAttribute('href'),
         'title' => $lnk->getAttribute('title')
      );
      }
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($links); echo '</pre>';
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the array directly in a way that is usable afterwards?

```
<?php
$searched = file_get_contents('http://technologijos.lt');
$xml = new DOMDocument();
@$xml->loadHTML($searched);

$links = [];
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $lnk) {
    $links[] = sprintf(
        '%s : %s', 
        $lnk->getAttribute('href'), 
        $lnk->getAttribute('title');
    );
}

var_dump(implode(', ', $links);
```

Obviously the same can be done by using a second loop to iterate over the links array if it is create as shown in your example.

Comment: Thank you, maybe could I ask as one more question - how I can align the output, that links would be in one side and titles afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, but that is a completely different question. It basically asks: "how does html layouting work" which is something that cannot be answered in the question-and-answer-style used here at SO. I suggest you look for a few basic "getting started" tutorials about html (there are tons of those), look at a few examples. I am certainly that you will easily get an idea.